In input process output is it still the input stage if i need a logic to get the data first?
For example, if I have a list of orders coming in the request, and if an order have a list of items, and if i need to merge items, summing their value, for orders with the same id, if i do this stage of preparing the data so that then i can get and set the values, would this step be violating the input process output model?
